# How might you create new subpages when api (json) changes?

Tags: javascript, json, api, deep-linking, mixcloud

I want to use data from the api from Mixcloud (audio hosting service like soundcloud) such that a new subpage(is it called deeplink?) is created when a new post is posted to Mixcloud.

My project is a website for a podcast. I am imagining the index.html featuring every podcast episode in a list, with subpages each dedicated to a single episode. [mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQE6Z.png)

I'm very new to web development so please bear with me. I would therefore love references/material to read.

I have figured out how to get data from the JSON api parse it into Javascript strings and change the innerHTML of elements in the index.html.

I'm having difficulty understanding how you might go about generating the new subpages whenever a new post is posted to Mixcloud.

I'm also having difficulty searching for the right material to read about this, probably because I don't know the right words and terms to search for.

Here's a snippet of my code so far. And the [API / JSON file](https://api.mixcloud.com/radiomodem/cloudcasts/) that I'm using.

```
<div class="episode">
    <div class="episode-title">Loading episode...</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
    <div class="episode-title">Loading episode...</div>
</div>
<div class="episode">
    <div class="episode-title">Loading episode...</div>
</div>
```

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

        //parse JSON to javascript objects
        var response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

        //array of the first 3 podcast episodes
        var episodes = document.getElementsByClassName("episode");

        //array of the first 3 podcast episode titles
        var episodeTitles = document.getElementsByClassName("episode-title");

        //loop to update innerHTML
        for(var i = 0; i < episodes.length; i++) {
            var episodeTitle = response.data[i].name;
            episodeTitles[i].innerHTML = episodeTitle;
        }
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "https://api.mixcloud.com/radiomodem/cloudcasts/", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are expecting to be able to create a hierarchical structure of pages with client side code. I suggest starting some reading around [client vs server](https://www.seguetech.com/client-server-side-code/). This link being the first google search result.

If you plan on doing this in javascript as client side code, the pages you create will not physically exist. You would be creating a [Single Page Application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) that references resources that look like pages but are only stored in memory. Delivery of those pages would be made through a [client side router](https://medium.com/@wilbo/server-side-vs-client-side-routing-71d710e9227f), without a web request to a server resource being made. With a Single Page Application approach, you would not be able to present the same cached version of a Mixcloud post to multiple users; the in-memory pages you create would only exist in an individual users browser.

You need to split your code into separate server and client code bases for this to work properly.

Your server would make the requests to https://api.mixcloud.com/radiomodem/cloudcasts/ and create a new physical subpage file for each child page. Your home page could read the contents of the subpage directory and present these as navigateable choices.

On the client side all you have is html.

If you want to stick with only learning 1 language I suggest using [Node with Express](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction). This would allow you to run JavaScript on the server.